# layer dependence about network

Tags: networking, layer

i have a question about network layer, that is:

as we all know, in layer architecture, the N+2 layer should only depends on the N+1 layer, while knows nothing about N layer. for example, in a typical application, the web layer should only depends on the business logic layer, but not the data access layer

when it comes to computer network, things seem to be different. In application layer, program has to know not only transmition layer(TCP port), but also network layer(IP address)

this confuse me, what do you think about this?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Unforunately life isn't really like that. TCP/IP for example violates the principle in several ways. The OSI stack tried not to, but where is it today?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

generally you are right. Unfortunately borders between layers in networks are kinda blurry, not just because we have a standard which is not used (OSI) and de facto standard which does not enforce the idea you mentioned, but also because the protocols are often not strictly bound to one layer but can do stuff on more then one of them. Good amount of protocols is developed before the OSI model and before they were standardized and then it was already too late to make some radical changes. So there are protocols that are considered to be between two layers (or on both layers) like MPLS, ARP etc. And protocols that are based on another protocol which is on the same layer, like OSPF that runs on top of IP even if they are considered to be on L3.

What you mentioned is another example. The reason for that is that addressing is not done on the most-upper layer (application layer) but on network layer (for host/network adapter) and transport layer (for process/application). So you need to know the IP address and port number (and actually a protocol) to be able to address the remote application. That's where the network sockets come in as an gateway (or API) between application and the network. So, even if you are technically correct about defying the principle of layered model, you are not really doing anything on L3 or L4 (but you can;) ). You don't need to fragment packets, handle retransmissions or worry about error corrections etc., you are just passing down the required addressing information when creating a socket.

TCP/IP is more oriented towards the feasibility of implementation, where OSI is more concerned about the standard then the implementation of that standard. This has it's bad and good sides. The ability to freely implement the protocol can be an advantage if you use that power well and since you are not strictly bound to some specification you can do some things more efficiently... or fail epically. The drawbacks of mixing 'responsibilities' are obvious and great example are protocols like H.323 which embed the IP addresses inside user's payload so if you want to do NAT for example you need to inspect the payload, change IP addresses, recalculate checksums, and stuff like that instead of just handling the translation on network layer.

Why are stuff still like this? Probably because there is no easy way to change any of that because of sheer number of devices and protocols, applications, etc that needs to be updated and this takes a lot of time. Just look at the speed of adopting IPv6 which has been around for more then 15 years.

Comment: thank you so much. you explained it very clearly, not only answer my question, but also resolve some basic ideas.